# WooCommerce cart update causes section to disappear after AJAX refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm experiencing a peculiar issue with my WooCommerce cart where the coupon section disappears after an AJAX refresh, but only under specific conditions. The problem arises when:

1. A coupon is applied to the cart.
2. The quantity of an item is then updated.
3. The "Update cart" button is pressed.
4. Post-AJAX, the coupon section completely vanishes.

However, if a product is removed from the cart, the subsequent AJAX update causes the coupon section to reappear. This unexpected behavior occurs without any evident errors in the JavaScript console.

Here's the problematic section handling the coupon application and the update button:

```
<div class="cart-coupon-container">
    <!-- Coupon and update button -->
    <button type="submit" class="button update-cart" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </button>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
    <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) : ?>
        <div class="coupon">
            <label for="coupon_code" class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                <?php esc_html_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            </button>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I expect the coupon section to remain visible and functional after any AJAX updates in the cart. For a clearer understanding of the issue, I have attached a video demonstrating the problem:
https://share.zight.com/z8udgzYx

Any insights into what might be causing this behavior or suggestions for a fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It very much looks like in response to the AJAX request, the whole cart gets replaced. So you'd have to look for the reason on the server side then - apparently something prevents the coupon section from getting rendered into the generated output. Maybe some plugin is hooking into `woocommerce_cart_coupon` in a faulty way.